# jquery .css() is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css

i wrote a code for fading effect on a `div` in jquery.

```
$("#trigger").click(function(e){
    $("#divid").parent().css("background-color","#D18F8F");
    console.log($("#divid").parent().css("background-color"));
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#divid").offset().top},'slow');
    $("#divid").parent().css("transition","background-color 2s linear");
    $("#divid").parent().css("background-color","transparent");
});
```

when first time i clicked on `#trigger` it worked as expected, but next time i clicked on trigger it is just not working.
here is console output
`rgb(209, 143, 143)` for the first time and `rgba(0,0,0,0)` for all next time.

**EDIT**: here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R756M/)

Comment: In witch browser are you working?

Comment: @AlexandreDiacov Chrome 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your background color to #D18F18F fast you have to remove the transition. Else wise you would have to wait 2s again before #divid has the new background color.

Add this at the first line of your .click function:

```
$("#divid").parent().css("transition","none");
```

Comment: but in my problem, i waited for 2 sec and this is not showing again

Comment: @optional optional It requires 2s from the moment you click on the trigger. 
@ A. Wolff how can you edit my answer? (And how do I insert code the right way, the code block didn't seem to work when I tried it).

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery-UI and you can use.......

```
$("#trigger").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#divid").offset().top},'slow');
    $(".abc").animate({backgroundColor:"#D18F8F"},2000);
    $(".abc").animate({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R756M/4/)

Comment: You should say: <<If you are **already** using jQuery UI, you can use...>>

Comment: He did not have it added as a library in his fiddle.